How to Dynamically Update initialDay in DayView Widget from calendar_view Package in Flutter?
I'm using the DayView widget from the calendar_view (https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_view) package in my Flutter app to display events for a selected day. I want to dynamically update the initialDay of DayView whenever a new date is selected from a calendar. However, changing the initialDay value doesn't seem to update the DayView.
Here's a simplified version of my code:


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:calendar_view/calendar_view.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class HourlyView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<EventModel> events;
  final DateTime initialDate;

  HourlyView({required this.events, required this.initialDate});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    EventController eventController = EventController();

    // Map EventModel to CalendarEventData and add to controller
    events.forEach((event) {
      eventController.add(
        CalendarEventData(
          date: event.start,
          startTime: event.start,
          endTime: event.end,
          title: event.summary,
        ),
      );
    });

    return Container(
      color: Colors.black, // Set the background color to black
      child: DayView(
        controller: eventController,
        initialDay: initialDate,
        // Other properties...
      ),
    );
  }
}



Even though the initialDay is updated, the DayView does not refresh to show the new date. How can I ensure that the DayView updates correctly when the initialDay changes?
Additional Context:

I'm using a ValueNotifier to handle the selected date changes in my calendar view.
The DayView widget seems to initialize with the correct date but does not update dynamically.


Hi I have the same problem, with a slightly different implementation specifically in:

I'm using only the StatefulWidget in handling my state changes
I'm using a CalendarControllerProvider to handle DayView and WeekView interchangeably using TabBar

environment:

calendar_view (package) = v.1.2.0
flutter = v.3.22.1

base on your implementation I have also tried the following below code.
I was able to solve it by this
class CustomDayView<T extends Object?> extends DayView<T> {
  CustomDayView({
    super.key,
    super.controller,
    super.initialDay,
  });

  @override
  GlobalKey<DayViewState<T>> key = GlobalKey<DayViewState<T>>();
}

class HourlyView extends StatelessWidget {
  //... your code
  //... your code
  //... your code

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //... your code
    //... your code
    //... your code

    return Container(
      color: Colors.black, // Set the background color to black
      child: CustomDayView(
        controller: eventController,
        initialDay: initialDate,
        // Other properties...
      ),
    );
  }
}

I made a custom class CustomDayView which extends the DayView Widget
and what specifically makes it work is this
  @override
  GlobalKey<DayViewState<T>> key = GlobalKey<DayViewState<T>>();

I actually don't know why it works in my end, I have tried reading about what does it do when overriding the GlobalKey but I just don't understand, sorry.
What have I tried doing before I came up with the above code (Note: I have tried doing this and I can't make it to work):

trace the DayView Widget and its State Widget checking if somehow there's a way to trigger to change the _currentDate from outside the package/library
or maybe somehow call the jumpToPage or jumpToDate after my date state change
tinker if maybe the controller can be manipulate or change so that it will trigger the date base on my state changes

I'm not sure if there a better way for me to work with this, but right now I'll just do what works I guess.
Sorry if somehow my English is not good or any misspelled or grammatical error I actually don't know, just want to share what I came up of.
